# How to lowercase item value in iterator-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

How can I lowercase a variable value in maven .pom ?
Basically I have the variable item which contains the value : ar-WW

I need to pass this variable value in a file path but it has to be lower case.

**Here is my code:**

```
<dir>/opt/Data</dir>
...............
<items>
   <item>ar-WW</item>
   ......
<items>
................
<copy todir="${item}/data/val">
   <fileset dir="${dir}/content/${item}/lements" erroronmissingdir="true">
        <include name="**/*"/>
   </fileset>
</copy>
................
```

What I need is fileset dir to be : /opt/Data/content/ar-ww/lements

I cannot change the item value as I need the version containing upper cases too.

I'm on maven 3.5.0.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to my problem by using itemsWithProperties instead of items

```
 <configuration>
                    <itemsWithProperties>
                        <itemWithProperty>
                            <name>ar-WW</name>
                            <properties>
                                <lowercase>ar-ww</lowercase>
                            </properties>
                        </itemWithProperty>
```